# NOT LIKE with nested SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have a table that holds phone number values which can also be wildcard like the % mentioned below

`select phonenumber from table_2 ;`

```
  1    5159199076
  2    210645%
  3    %0869067
```

I need help with the SQL query to exclude all values of the phone number that exist in table_2

So table_1 has these values

```
ID     Phonenumber
   101     9757895378
   201   **2106450789**
   301   **9190869067**
   401     8757895078
```

```
select table_1.phone_number
from table_1
where table_1.phone_number not in 
(
  select phonenumber from table_2
  where phonenumber = table_1.phonenumber)
```

This works if there is no wildcard in table_2 like  *210645%* or *%0869067*

I updated the SQL

```
select table_1.phone_number
from table_1
where table_1.phone_number not like 
(
  select phonenumber from table_2
  )
```

which results in no rows being returned,How do I modify the SQL to get the right result so that the wildcards are not included? DB is postgres.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE ANY` to compare with all elements in a subselect:

```
SELECT table_1.phone_number
FROM table_1
WHERE NOT table_1.phone_number
          LIKE ANY (array(
                       SELECT table_2.phone_number
                       FROM table_2
                   ));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still returns the same values that it should ignore based on wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table_1.phone_number
from table_1
where table_1.phone_number not in 
(
  select phonenumber from table_2)
```

Comment: Would be nice if you'd add some explanation about the code